# How do I research obscure file types?

Tags: file-format

A client has a large document-management system -- millions of TIFFs and PDFs and a fewer of other random files; images and other binaries.  I'm converting formats, imprinting notes, reorganizing and redacting sensitive information when found.  And that's all great for the vast bulk of the files.

But I occasionally find a new format and have to figure out what it is and how to handle it within the project's parameters.  Usually this isn't too hard and when it has been, it's such a small handful that it doesn't matter too much if I just can't handle it.  But right now, I have a larger handful of files that don't appear to have a sophisticated header but all start with "COM1.0" (43 4F 4D 31 2E 30).

So, I'd like help on two levels.  What's a good way for me to research this (and others I might find in the future -- teach a man to fish, and all); when just Googling around fails me?  And if you know what the file type is, I'd be keen to hear about it.

Comment: I might be able to help a little since I'm doing the same exact thing. And I'm stuck at the same place. I've googled a lot and cannot find out what kind of file this is. I believe it to be compressed COLD text done with PKZIP. However, I have not been able to un-compress it. COLD text is (Computer Output to Laser Disk) data. Did you ever find anything out?

Comment: I too am facing the same conundrum.  I am also dealing with a "large document-management system" (probably the same one) and there are quite a few of those "COM1.0" files that I can't identify.

Comment: Sorry guys, I don't have any great advice.  We never did figure out what those files were and just told our client that we couldn't process them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One specialist site is http://www.wotsit.org/ - there may be a few others. These give details when you can already identify the file format, though.

There are some more tips at http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

I did try doing a little searching and didn't turn up anything much, but I didn't try very hard.

Answer (score 4):

Good luck, but remember that not every file format is documented outside of the company that created it; and, few companies publish their file formats before they go under.

Depending on how old these files are, the odds of hitting a brick wall are high unless you have a few extra hints to work with (like the name of the program the files are associated with).

Comment: No votes left :( But I like this idea: have the customer tell you the name of the program(s) they use (or have used) in accessing said files, if possible.

Comment: I like that idea too, but they're just like a giant vacuum-cleaner sucking up documents from *their* clients, regardless of format or source.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Google](http://www.google.com/)
2. If google fails, it may be something specific for your customer.

Comment: However, the supplied header information is very hard -- if not [near] impossible -- to Google for. So just a "google it" isn't terribly helpful here :-/

Comment: @pst somewhere else? It wasn't supposed to be terribly helpful however :) That was what the second point about.